# IPOJO :providing security to an application

Tags: java, xml, osgi, ipojo

> How IPOJO provides security to an OSGI application  using an xml file
>        and java class !?
>   i want to use the proprities `H` and `L` but i dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically iPOJO is compliant with OSGi security. However the iPOJO bundle should be granted all permissions (as most of the frameworks).

Comment: My objectif is to give previlege to bundles  for exemple a bundles who has H property should comunicate only with others wich have the same property

Comment: To implement this, you should have a look to Service Interceptors: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-advanced-topics/service-binding-interceptors.html